# If f is continuous at the point a, there exists a number δ > 0 such that f(x) is continuous on (a − δ, a + δ).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

"If f is continuous at the point a, there exists a number δ > 0 such

that f(x) is continuous on (a − δ, a + δ)."

Can f(x)=x^(1/2) be a counter example to above statement? at x=0?

Comment: Consider $f(1/n) = 1/n, n=1,2,\dots,\, f(x) = 0\,$ everywhere else. Take $a=0.$

Answer (score 2):

No, because $ \sqrt{x} $ isn't defined for negative $x$, hence it has no properties in that range at all.

(constructive) Edit.  Consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \tan(x),& \text{if $x$ is irrational};\\
x,& \text{if $x$ is rational}.
\end{cases}$$
is even differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(x)=1$ but not continuous in any neighborhood of $0$.